# change the date format in a csv file

Tags: python, r, excel, cmd

I have a huge CSV file, the 6th column in the file is named "date" , I want to change the format of the entries in this column from whatever format they have to yyyy-mm-dd format.

I only know how to change the date format using Excel but this file is too big to be opened by excel.

Thanks

Comment: What format are they in?

Comment: most of the entries have dd/mm/yyyy format

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: "whatever format they have" - which leaves the question, how to decide, if `05-08-2015` means "fifth of august" or "eighth of may"

Comment: @Stephan, exactly that is why I asked, you could use dateutil but for the reason you mentioned it could give the wrong output

Comment: yes, you are right, I didn't a clear explanation, the current format is dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: If you can get the question reopened, there is an easy solution in `Powershell`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can read the file into R, you can use

```
library(lubridate)
YourData$date <- dmy(YourData$date)
YourData$date <- format(YourData$date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

And then write back to the file, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting to a datetime just split om `/` and use `str.format` to swap the year and day:

```
import csv
from shutil import move
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
with open("infile", 'rb') as csvfile, NamedTemporaryFile(dir=".",delete=False) as temp:
    w = csv.writer(temp)
    r = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in r:
        dt = row[5].split("/")
        row[5] = "{}/{}/{}".format(row[-1],row[1],row[0])
        w.writerow(row)

move(temp.name,"infile")
```

Writing the updated rows to a `NamedTemporaryFile` and using shutil.move to replace the original file with the modified content.